# How do you add a native library (.so) to android studio?

Tags: java, android, .so

I am currently getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ryane.jzy-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib] couldn't find "libgluegen-rt.so"
```

While performing the following line of code

```
System.loadLibrary("gluegen-rt");
```

I've included the following in my build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs", "$buildDir/native-libs"]
    }
}
```

And have placed my libgluegen.so within src/main/jniLibs. According to the error it seems as if it isn't looking in the directory I specified. Are there steps that I'm missing?

Comment: Try to add `jni.srcDirs = []` to `build.gradle`  `sourceSets.main`

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same error. I've been reading around and notice a lot of people mentioning .mk files when using native libraries. Are those required? @RustFisher

Comment: `.mk` file means you compile the `.so` by yourself. So do you have a native lib(like C/C++ files) in your project or just `.so`  files ? You need to compile the C/C++ source files by using NDK tools.

Comment: There are no C/C++ files, only .so

Comment: Could you paste the `.so` files path ?

Comment: Copying the path leads to the same error

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Actually I want to see your `.so` path...
And for example, in my build.gradle 
`jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']` .

The path of `.so` is `MyProj\app\src\main\libs\armeabi-v7a\libSmartAlgorithm.so` .

libs/TARGET_ARCH_ABI

```
arm64-v8a
armeabi
armeabi-v7a
mips
mips64
x86
x86_64
```

Comment: My error was that I was storing my files directly inside main\libs instead of their respective architecture directories! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I want to add them too but where would I get them I do not know